# Meteor + Mongodb full text search

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to implement full text search on a mongodb (version 3.0.1) collection through an index. I create the index through the `_ensureINdex` method during startup on the server side, and then I manually verify its existence (it exists). Then I built out a trivial function housed in `Meteor.methods` that takes some data (namely, a string) and implements a search on the indexed collection.

```
mySearchFunction: function(data) { 
   var res = MyCollection.find({$text: {$search: data } });
   console.log(res); 
   return res; 
}
```

However, the log spits out this rather verbose error.

```
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?      _oplogHandle: null,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?      db: 
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?       { domain: null,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         _events: {},
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         _maxListeners: 10,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         databaseName: 'meteor',
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         serverConfig: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         options: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         _applicationClosed: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         slaveOk: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         bufferMaxEntries: -1,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         native_parser: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         bsonLib: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         bson: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         bson_deserializer: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         bson_serializer: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.976(-4)?         _state: 'connected',
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         pkFactory: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         forceServerObjectId: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         safe: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         notReplied: {},
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         isInitializing: true,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         openCalled: true,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         commands: [],
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         logger: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         tag: 1427039797274,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         eventHandlers: [Object],
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         serializeFunctions: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         raw: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         recordQueryStats: false,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         numberOfRetries: 60,
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?         readPreference: [Object] },
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?      _primary: null },
I20150322-11:57:49.977(-4)?   _cursorDescription: 
I20150322-11:57:49.978(-4)?    { collectionName: 'myCollection',
I20150322-11:57:49.978(-4)?      selector: { '$text': [Object] },
I20150322-11:57:49.978(-4)?      options: { transform: null } },
I20150322-11:57:49.978(-4)?   _synchronousCursor: null }
I20150322-11:57:49.981(-4)? Internal exception while processing    message { msg: 'method',
I20150322-11:57:49.981(-4)?   method: 'myIndexMethod',
I20150322-11:57:49.982(-4)?   params: [ 'someString' ],
I20150322-11:57:49.982(-4)?   id: '10' } Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined
```

Comment: console.log(res.fetch()) will return an array, you won't read much from cursor you return above

Comment: The stack trace is referring to `myIndexMethod`, maybe you should add this method to your problem description? Maybe comparing your implementation to the example referenced at the bottom of [this post](http://random-notes-chris.blogspot.com/2015/03/full-text-search-for-meteor.html) can help?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. I managed to figure out what was wrong and got the error to stop, I am now suffering with a different problem...